# Can I add data from different tables of the same database into each row of a ListView in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

Can I add data from different tables of the same database into each row of a ListView in Android?

I have a vendor app and I want to add data from one standard items list table and one daily table to the list view.

Comment: just a note: you don't have to use a `Cursor`/`CursorAdapter` to populate a `ListView`.  You can fill your own custom list/array with objects from any source(multiple tables, string resources, etc)

Comment: how do I fill the listView from a database without a cursor?

Answer (score 0):

If both tables have the same row format (or at least you're selecting the same type of rows from both tables), you can combine them into a single query with UNION.  See the [sqlite select query documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html) for more info on UNIONs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean that the query joins two different tables; is that correct?

If you're using a [SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html), then you can use a [CursorToStringConverter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.CursorToStringConverter.html) to provide the labels for the ListView. Here's an example:

```
    // choices to be displayed in the AutoCompleteTextView.
    adapter.setCursorToStringConverter(new CursorToStringConverter() {
        public String convertToString(android.database.Cursor cursor) {
            final int columnIndex1 = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("col1");
            final String str1 = cursor.getString(columnIndex1);
            final int columnIndex2 = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("col2");
            final String str2 = cursor.getString(columnIndex2);
            return str1 + str2;
        }
    });
```

If you want to data from each of the tables to be presented in separate Views (instead of within a single TextView), then you can use a [SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder.html) to update the Views. ([Here's an example](http://www.outofwhatbox.com/blog/2010/12/android-spinners-simpleadapter-and-maybe-viewbinder/) of a ViewBinder. I wrote this to work with a Spinner, but it works the same way with a ListView.)